# 'Method name must be a string' when using __call method in php

Tags: php

I am using the magic __call method in PHP. Sometimes the function I call is a number. For example the class name is example, then sometimes I want to call example::32

Is this possible or should I look at another alternative.

Comment: I don't think that `32` is a valid name for a function.

Comment: I don't think `32` is a sane name for a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible.  You just need to change the call syntax.  `$foo->32()` is not valid and will give a fatal error.  But `$foo->{'32'}()` is valid syntax.  Now, you can't define a function 32, but you can use __call to execute it...

```
class Foo {
    public function __call($f, $args) {
        echo $f;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;

$foo->32();  //Fatal Error

$foo->{32}(); //Fatal Error

$foo->{'32'}(); // "32" is printed

$x = 32;
$foo->$x(); //Fatal Error

$x = '32';
$foo->$x(); // "32" is printed

$x = 32;
$foo->{(string)$x}(); // "32" is printed

call_user_func(array($foo, '32')); // "32" is printed
```

Or in 5.3 with static methods, it gets a bit harder:

```
class Foo {
    public static function __callStatic($f, $args) {
        echo $f;
    }
}

Foo::32();  //Fatal Error
Foo::{32}(); //Fatal Error
Foo::{'32'}(); //Fatal Error

$x = 32;
Foo::$x(); //Fatal Error

$x = '32';
Foo::$x(); // "32" is printed

$x = 32;
Foo::{(string)$x}(); //Fatal Error

call_user_func(array('foo', '32')); //Fatal Error
```

Comment: Do you have any idea if this works in combination with the function method_exists. this does not work: method_exists('Foo','32');

Comment: `method_exists()` only works with defined functions.  So any call that would result in `__call()` being executed will return false...

Comment: do you have any idea how I can check if the function is going to pass. Because I have to check if the function passes for some other methodes, not all are magic.

Comment: You don't need to check...  In `__call()`, check if it can handle the method.  If not, `throw new BadMethodCallException('This Function Does Not Exist');`.  Then, just try{}catch(){} the exception.  That way, you try to process it, and then if it fails, you know the method doesn't exist...  Either that, or add a method `isCallable($name){}` that returns a bool.  The body would be something like `return method_exists($this, $name) || in_array($this->methods);` where `$this->methods` contains all the methods that __call() can handle...

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible as `32` is not a valid property name. You will get a parse error like:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in …

Furthermore `example::32` would refer to a static attribute and not a method (`example::32()` would if `32` would be a valid name, but you need to use [`__callStatic`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) to fetch these calls).

If you want to access non-existing attributes, use the [magic methods `__get` and `__set`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) instead.

Comment: @Saif Bechan: But why would you want to call such a method? What’s the purpose?

Comment: For example I have a class 'questions' with a method 'list'. This lists all the questions. questions->list(). Now I want to create a magic function __call. If I call questions->32() I want to display question with id 32.

Comment: @Saif Bechan: Well, the comprehensive way would be to name the method `get` or `getById` if there are more ways to get a question/several questions.